# Downloading files in Windows 8 through a browser

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

Under Windows 7 when I click the following link an Excel file gets downloaded to my machine and I can easily open the file for viewing (regardless of the browser used IE, Chrome, Firefox)

http://imagehost.bigwavesoftware.net/1.xlsx

However, if I click on it with a Windows 8 machine (again, regardless of the browser), I am not able to easily open the file. I have to manually save it to disk, and then open it from there.

Is this a limitation with Windows 8?

Also, I think I have the correct Stack site for this question, but I appreciate advice on where to post this if this site isn't appropriate.

Comment: What security software are you using? I have not experienced this issue in Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: Were you able to click the above link and have it download the file?  My users are reporting Windows asks to choose which software to open the file with, but Excel is not one of the options provided.  Also, they have Excel mapped to the .xlsx extension and double clicking an Excel file from their file system works fine.

Comment: I did not have any issues downloading or viewing the file.

Comment: What behavior exactly is different between Windows 7 and 8 in your experience? By "manually" save it, do you mean you have to right-click it? I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: You need to be more clear about “can’t easily open” so you can or can’t open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your Excel installation on the Windows 8 machine. Yous should consider a repair or reinstallation of Excel and/or Office. Both desktop and modern-ui browsers should give the option to immediately open the file after downloading when the Excel file types are correctly registered. I have tested this with Windows 8 Pro and Excel installed with default settings.